# Если не брать выражение в скобки - будет другой результат

Tags: c#, математика

Есть код:

```
double result = 0;
        for (double i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            result += 1 / ((2 * i) + 1) * ((2 * i) + 1);
        }

        return result;
```

Почему в данном случае к переменной `result` просто добавляется каждый раз единица, а если поставить скобки в выражении вот так:

```
result += 1 / (((2 * i) + 1) * ((2 * i) + 1));
```

то в таком случае считает правильно, так как и должно работать. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Действия выполняются по порядку слева направо. этаж математика 3 класс

Comment: потому что если 1 поделишь на `x`, а потом умножишь на `x`, то будет 1. `1 / x * x = 1`, а если `1 / (x*x) = 1/ x^2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приоритет операций деления и умножения одинаков, а сами операции левоассоциатвные, то есть выполняются слева направо. Поэтому выражение

```
1 / ((2 * i) + 1) * ((2 * i) + 1);
```

вычисляется по правилам так: сначала идет деление, при этом делитель в скобках вычисляется в свою очередь по тем де правилам: сначала умножение (тут можно было и без скобок обойтись), затем сложение. После того как делитель вычислен, выполняется деление. Затем - умножение, при этом правый множитель вычисляется как и делитель.

А вот здесь

```
1 / (((2 * i) + 1) * ((2 * i) + 1));
```

при вычислении делителя вычисляется все выражение в скобках - скобки имеют наивысший приоритет, так что умножение вычисляется при вычислении делителя, до самого деления.

Скобки для того и используют, чтобы менять порядок выполнения операций, не по приоритету.

Обратите внимание, что

```
1 / (((2 * i) + 1) * ((2 * i) + 1));
```

это то же, что и

```
1 / ((2 * i) + 1) / ((2 * i) + 1);
```

Правда, математически, а не в смысле порядка вычислений.